# ObservableCollection didn't Bind the data in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox, observablecollection

I need to show the WCF service Return Value(LIST) in Silverlight Listbox.

create GetAllAgents  Class like,

```
  public class GetAllAgents
    {
        public List<string> FirstName { get; set; }


        public GetAllAgents(List<string> firstName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
        }
    }
```

The Following Method used for Consume the WCF Service

```
    public partial class AgentQueue : UserControl
    {
        ChatACDService.ChatACDServiceClient ChatAcdClient = new ChatACDService.ChatACDServiceClient();
        public ObservableCollection<GetAllAgents> _GetAllAgents = new ObservableCollection<GetAllAgents>();

        public AgentQueue()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadAgentList();
            this.AllList.DataContext = _GetAllAgents;

        }


        private void LoadAgentList()
        {
            ChatAcdClient.GetAllAgentListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetAllAgentListCompletedEventArgs>(ChatAcdClient_GetAllAgentListCompleted);
            ChatAcdClient.GetAllAgentListAsync();


        }
        void ChatAcdClient_GetAllAgentListCompleted(object sender, GetAllAgentListCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                //   AllAgents.ItemsSource = e.Result;
                _GetAllAgents.Add(new GetAllAgents(e.Result.ToList()));
            }
        }
```

I use the following code For create List Box in XAML page

```
 <ListBox x:Name="AllList" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
           DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
        Margin="403,54,0,35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="101" />
```

But The Output like ,

[image]

I need to show the WCF method's result(return type is list) in Listbox by using ObservableCollection.What are the changes are need to make in above Program?

Comment: Show how you set DataContext.

Comment: @Maximus this.AllList.DataContext = _GetAllAgents; the AllList is name of the Listbox

Comment: What do you expect? The object returned by `FirstName` is exactly the list you see in the output. What did you expect to get as output?

Comment: You are binding to GetAllAgents and it shows one row that means that GetAllAgentListAsync return one element. GetAllAgents class has only List so what do you expect to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works pretty well:

You ask to display the Member Path "FirstName" of your object GetAllAgents.
But the Member Path "FirstName" is a list of string.

So your XAML display what you expect from it: the toString() conversion of your memberPath.

And the default toString of your member path which is FirstName which is a list of string is: System.Collection.Generic.List[System.String]

I guess what you expect is that your list of first name should be the item source of your ListBox.

So if your only need is to display their firstName, just replace

```
public ObservableCollection<GetAllAgents> _GetAllAgents = new ObservableCollection<GetAllAgents>();
```

By

```
public ObservableCollection<string> _GetAllAgents = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

and

```
_GetAllAgents.Add(new GetAllAgents(e.Result.ToList()));
```

By

```
foreach (var agentName in e.Result.ToList())
{
_GetAllAgents.Add(agentName);
}
```

And it will display the name of your agent.

If you need mor than that, you will need to create a viewModel per agent object and a dataTemplate to let know Silverlight how you want it to be display.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Am new to silverlight Applications.How can I Show all the List Values in Listbox instead system.collections.generic.list1 system.string

Comment: Did you put a break point to be sure your server return a list of string as result?